# Lookup Columns in Word desktop are greyed out in properties pane

Tags: sharepoint-server, lookup-column, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

I am working with SP on Prem 2019. Users perform File->Save As from word or excel desktop apps and try to save it to the desired document library in sharepoint. The save fails as it expects required metadata to be populated prior to save. For some reason, lookup columns are greyed out.

I have seen in some cases where if 'Show Details' is clicked, it opens up separate window where lookup field value can be populated but in my case, its greyed out and can't be clicked, see screenshot below.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Deal Name and Document type are both lookup columns and the threshold count is not exceeded at all. Is this a behavior by design, if someone came across this and found a solution , please shed light.
Thanks in advance.

P.S: I tried this on sharepoint online too and was able to reproduce same issue. Not sure if its a behavior by design.

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce this issue, in my testing, it showed as:
[image]

What version of Office did you use? Office 2016 or Office 2019? Please make sure you have installed latest CU for your Office, then test again.

Comment: Thanks Kally, the installed version is Office 2016 professional plus. Can you help me with the URL of the latest CU, want to make sure I do the right one. Also sorry but what does CU stand for?

Comment: Any thoughts @Kally_MSFT.